# How to have one array to Store a String and another to cout how many times that String was used?

Tags: java, arraylist, counter

I'm making an app for an ice cream shop where I need at some point to know how many ice cream from a specific flavor were sold. I have to write the flavor of the ice cream when I add it to the stock, so the `ArrayList` that contains the flavor is initially empty. Then I need another `ArrayList` which is going to store the number of times that flavor is sold. I need to do it with two `ArrayList`s because I don't understand `HashMap`s yet.

```
IceCream newIceCream = new IceCream();
Integer id = Console.readInt("Id: ");
String name = Console.readString("Ice cream name: ");
Float price = (float)Console.readDouble("Price: ");
String flavour = Console.readString("Flavour: ");

newIceCream.setId(id);
newIceCream.setNome(name);
newIceCream.setPreco(price);
newIceCream.setSabor(flavour);

iceCreamStock.add(newIceCream);
```

This is how I create the ice cream.

```
Integer sellIceCream = Console.readInt("Which ice cream to sell? (id)");
boolean iceCreamExists = false;
for (int i = 0; i < iceCreamStock.size() && iceCreamExists == false; i++) {
    if (iceCreamStock.get(i).getId() == sellIceCream) {
        iceCreamExists = true;
    }
    if (iceCreamExists == true) {
        soldIceCream.add(iceCreamStock.get(i));
        iceCreamStock.remove(i);
        salesCounter++;
        System.out.println("Ice cream sold.");
    }
}
if (iceCreamExists == false) {
    System.out.println("Ice cream not found");
}
```

This is how I sell it. I know I have to work somewhere in these two parts of the program, just can't figure out how.

Comment: `soldIceCream` contains all the ice creams you sold, so you can count there how many were sold. What is it you can't do?

Comment: You already have an IceCream class.  Add a value to the class that represents the number of units sold.

Comment: I want to count only the different types of flavors sold. Thats why i need two separate arrays: one for the type of flavor and another one to count how many where sold. So, the counter needs to correspond with the type of flavor sold

Comment: _I don't understand `HashMap`s yet._ What's not to understand about class `java.util.HashMap`? Perhaps you mean you haven't learned about `HashMap` class yet so your professor said that you can't use that class?

Comment: yes, my prefessor told me to use only arrays. I've tried to learn Hashmaps but i couldn't wrap my head around it on my own. I prefer to work on this one as it was proposed and when I'm confortable move on to hasmaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use array-indexing to store the relationship between the arrays.

```
flavourList = List<String>
soldList = List<Integer> //initally all 0's
```

Whenever you add the icecream to the stock, check if the flavour of the ice-cream already exist in the array, if not add the flavour of the ice-cream into the flavourList at the end of the list.

```
if flavourList.indexOf("flavour") < 0:
    flavourList.add("flavour")
```

Now if the flavour is already present in the array, find the index and go to the same index in the soldList array and increment the current value by 1.

```
indexOfFlavour = flavourList.indexOf("flavour")
soldList.set(indexOfFlavour, soldList.get(indexOfFlavour) + 1)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was quite helpful.